# Отключить звук в IE

Tags: wsh, аудио, internet-explorer

Вечер добрый.

Есть скрипт скрытого открытия IE с заданной страницей/сайтом, но на этой странице/сайте есть звук который слышен при открытии сайта, т.е. сайта не видно, а звук его открытие выдает!

Можно ли выключить звук через скрипт?

```
 var WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
 WSHShell.Run("iexplore", 0);
```

Comment: Вообще было бы более верно создавать объект:  

    internetexplorer.application
и управлять им, но я например не нашел как выключить звук- отсутствует нормальная документация.  
Можно выключить звук в системе эмулируя нажатие клавиши mute:  

    WSHShell.SendKeys(chr(&hAD))
Второй вызов соответственно включит звук. Правда если звук был выключен, то наоборот первым вызовом он будет включен.